# AppleScript to choose item on web page

Tags: applescript, script, development

Is it possible with AppleScript to choose a clickable element in a web page and click it and if so, can you give me an example?

Comment: Thanks USER3439894 for the very comprehensive reply.  I will make good use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, generally speaking, it's possible, however it can depend on the browser and the web page, there is no *one method fits all*, if you will.

**Examples:**

Using this particular web page, looking at the question title line, to the far right is a blue button with says: **Ask Question**

The following line of **AppleScript** *code* will click that button in **Safari** *if* **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** is checked on the **Safari** > **Develop** menu, which is hidden by default and can be shown by checking **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar** in: **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Advanced**

```
tell application "Safari" to tell document 1 to do JavaScript ¬
    "document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0].click();"
```

With **Google Chrome** the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* does the same thing, without having to modify any of the default settings:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab in front window to execute javascript ¬
    "document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0].click();"
```

Note that the **JavaScript** *code* portion, within the double-quotes, of each of these is the same while the basic **AppleScript** *code* is different for how each of the two applications work with the *code*.

I should also point out that while this is **AppleScript**, albeit running some **JavaScript**, it's really the **JavaScript** that's doing the real work of clicking the target button. Basic vanilla **AppleScript** without executing some **JavaScript** cannot really click a button on the web page content unless it's done through the very kludgy use of **UI Scripting**.

**UI Scripting example:**

On my system, in **macOS High Sierra** using **Safari**, version 11.1.1 (13605.2.8), the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works to click the button that the other examples click.

```
tell application "System Events" to click UI element ¬
    "Ask Question" of group 5 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of ¬
    group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 of application process "Safari"
```

On my system, in  **Safari** on **macOS Catalina** you'd have to change `of group 5 of UI element 1` to `of group 6 of UI element 1`, and while that seems minor, nonetheless, it will depend on what you're trying to click and where and some objects on a web page may not be clickable at all with this method, yet will most likely be doable with **JavaScript** *calls*.

This wouldn't work in **Google Chrome** as it does not expose that particular `UI element` to click in this manner.

One of the issues with **UI Scripting** is the hierarchical structure to the *object* is subject to change between versions of the application or the versions of **macOS** and would need to be modified, where the use of **AppleScript** with **JavaScript** will typically continue to work without modification.

By the way, none of this is doable in **Firefox**.

Comment: ^ I would highly encourage OP to go with the Javascript option over UI scripting. While both are somewhat fragile, Javascript feels significantly less likely to break.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy, JavaScript is definitely the way to go, no doubt about it! UI Scripting should only be used when there is no better way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: ^^^^So envious.