# How do I use AppleScript to click buttons on a website?

Tags: applescript

I am looking for a way to use AppleScript to test my website.

Is there a way that I can make AppleScript click on different buttons and click on Text Input Fields using the JavaScript ID?

I am aware that there is a way to type using AppleScript.

Thanks!

Comment: Does my answer to this question answer your question? [AppleScript to choose item on web page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377071/applescript-to-choose-item-on-web-page)